# Inherit from template class problems

Tags: c++, templates, inheritance

Hi all I want to do something like this:

```
template<typename T>
struct APP_Interface{
    APP_Interface* shared;
    Mutex m; 
    T data;

    virtual void publish(){
    //copy data from this->data to shared->data
    }

    virtual void receive(){
    //copy data from shared->data to this->data 
    }
};

struct MyInterface : APP_Interface<MyInterface>{
    float MyData1;
    float MyData2;
};
```

I run (not so surprisingly I guess) into:

```
error: 'APP_Interface<T>::data' has incomplete type
error: forward declaration of 'struct MyInterface '
```

Are there any way around this?

**EDIT: What I am trying to achieve**

I have two threads. Thread1 produces real time data, and Thread2 consume these data. Now I want to let Thread1 share the data with Thread2 through shared data and a mutex.

Actually there's a lot of threads, and a lot of different data-interfaces sharing different data. Therefore I want an easy and elegant way to create and use the interfaces.

I want to create an interface something like this:

```
struct MyInterface : ??? {
    float MyData1;
    float MyData2;
};
```

Then when I should use it I simply want to:

```
//Thread1.hpp
class thread1{
    void run(){
        interface.MyData1 = 100; 
        interface.publish(); 
    }

public:
    MyInterface interface;
}

//And something similar for thread2 at the receiving end
```

Lastly I want to achieve some kine of "dependency injection" by letting main.c create the link between the two and allocating the shared structure. For example by:

```
//main.cpp
void main(){
    //Bind interfaces:
    MyInterface interface({ &thread1.interface,  //PROVIDER
                            &thread2.interface,  //CONSUMER
                          });
}
```

I have no idea if this explanation make sense :)

Comment: This does not make sense. What are you trying to achieve? Generally, you either want to make your derived class templated or you want to specialize APP_Interface. I'm guessing you want this: 'struct MyData {
    float MyData1;
    float MyData2;
}; APP_Interface<MyData> myDataPublisher;'

Comment: Well Obviosly this would fail. You'd have a MyInterface that was a App_Interface that contained a MyInterface that was a App_Interface that contained a... I don't think we can answer how to fix this problem unless you tell us how you plan on using this. Personally I'd make publish and recieve abstract and be done with it.

Comment: `T data;` should be `T* data;` Anyway look [**here**](http://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/More_C%2B%2B_Idioms/Curiously_Recurring_Template_Pattern) please, how to create and use  `CRTP` correctly.

Comment: I am trying to avoid dynamic memory ^^.

Comment: If you intend that `this->data` should represent the most derived part of `this`, then you don't need `T data`, you need `T* derived() { return static_cast<T*>(this); }`. That's just standard CRTP fare.

Answer (score 0):

1. Declare `data` to be a pointer.
2. Provide a getter and setter functions. In these functions, make sure that the data is allocated from heap.

Here's the updated class.

```
template<typename T>
struct APP_Interface{
    APP_Interface* shared;
    Mutex m; 
    T* data;

    APP_Interface : data(nullptr) {}

    T const& getData() const
    {
       if (!data)
       {
          data = new T;
       }
       return *data;
    }

    void setData(T const& newData)
    {
       if (!data)
       {
          data = new T;
       }
       *data = newData;
    }

    virtual void publish(){
    //copy data from this->data to shared->data
    }

    virtual void receive(){
    //copy data from shared->data to this->data 
    }
};
```

Comment: I am trying to avoid dynamic memory allocation :)

Comment: In that case, you have to find a different design for your classes. You can't use the CRTP pattern.